# How to use button id dynamic in post request in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am working with reactjs with axios. Currently, I am using get api to get a list. Each column has a unique id and I want to use this id for a new post API "post request" body.

**Button**

```
  <Button variant="outlined" color="primary" id={data.id} onClick={handleDialogOpenTwo}>
    Faq
  </Button>
```

**Post api and want to use here**

```
axios.post('https://gatewayapi.invest19.com/api/faqs',
  { 
    ipoId: '1511',   **i want to use this button id here**
    faqList:[
     { question: this.state.question, 
      answer: this.state.answer,
     }
    ]
  }
)
```

**Dialog**

```
  <Dialog open={isOpenTwo} onClose={handleDialogCloseTwo} className="quistion_Popup">
    {/* <DialogTitle>Confirm</DialogTitle> */}
    <DialogContent>
      <DialogContentText>Add Faq</DialogContentText>
      <FaqPage/>
    </DialogContent>

  </Dialog>
```

Comment: Have you tried  `e.traget.id` accessible from handleDialogOpenTwo ?

Comment: can u please give me a example @ArjunBiju

Comment: Can you please add the code of `handleDialogOpenTwo` function?

Comment: Added please check @Shahriar

Comment: I meant the function. `handleDialogOpenTwo( ) { ...  return blah blah blah }`

Comment: handleDialogOpenTwo using for open the Dialog @Shahriar

Answer (score 0):

```
const handleDialogOpenTwo = (e)=>{
 
 console.log(e.target.id);
 
 .... body of the function

}
```

you can access it like this